# Objective-C Travis failed for 'Test runner exited before starting test execution'

Tags: objective-c, ios-simulator, travis-ci

Here is my code in `.travis.yml` file，after run build is passing, but I found the TEST are failed. I have no idea about this and block me a few days, appreciate your help. THX

--- Error as below ---

```
2018-12-20 05:57:42.698 xcodebuild[2394:8186] [MT] 
IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (CB8F382A-5B77-4BDA-BC4F-6EDF7B7DB822) 
Beginning test session aaaaTests-CB8F382A-5B77-4BDA-BC4F-6EDF7B7DB822 at 2018- 
12-20 05:57:42.698 with Xcode 10A255 on target <DVTiPhoneSimulator: 
0x7f86387e49d0> {
    SimDevice: iPhone 6 (B25EC6DB-0B2F-4920-B6C2-8560331BA779, iOS 9.1, Booted)
} (9.1 (13B143))
2018-12-20 05:57:53.744 xcodebuild[2394:8186] [MT] 
IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 11.068 elapsed -- Testing started completed.
2018-12-20 05:57:53.744 xcodebuild[2394:8186] [MT] 
IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 0.000 sec, +0.000 sec -- start
2018-12-20 05:57:53.744 xcodebuild[2394:8186] [MT] 
IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 11.068 sec, +11.068 sec -- end
2018-12-20 05:57:53.746 xcodebuild[2394:8186] Error 
Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=6 "Early unexpected exit, 
operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Early unexpected exit, operation never 
finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x7f86389df930 {Error 
Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=5 "Test runner exited before 
starting test execution." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Test runner exited 
before starting test execution., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=If you believe 
this error represents a bug, please attach the result bundle at 
/Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aaaa- 
bdscsxnorhzvygafnsqdiqoriugx/Logs/Test/Run-aaaa-2018.12.20_05-57-22- 
+0000.xcresult}}}
Testing failed:
    aaaa.app (2488) encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted. Underlying error: Test runner exited before starting test execution.)
** TEST FAILED **
The command "set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace aaaa.xcworkspace -scheme aaaa -destination platform\=iOS\ Simulator,OS\=9.1,name\=iPhone\ 6 build test | xcpretty" exited with 65.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

---My code as below---

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode10
xcode_workspace: aaaa.xcworkspace
xcode_scheme: aaaa
xcode_destination: platform=iOS Simulator,OS=9.1,name=iPhone 6

before_install:
  - pod repo update
  - npm install ios-sim -g
  - ios-sim start --devicetypeid "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6, 9.1"
```

Comment: I suspect you are off-topic, this is not an objective-c related question: apparently it is a iOS simulator thing. By the way, did you try looking up for that error? There seem to be plenty of informations about it

Comment: @il3v um..the problem has block me a day, and search many solution , but still doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure the devices are correct? The fact that you are specifying their UDIDs doesn't smell right to me. Also, did you try and remove all of them and add them one by one and see if it isn't related to just one of the testing devices?

Comment: @il3v checked the UDID is all correct. I'm use Xcode10.1 to build, only the 12.1 device build and test success. others only build success and test failed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can fix by below step:

change the version of `osx_image` in `.travis.yml` file and retry

```
// if xcode10.1 build failed, you can change to other version, like xcode9.4
osx_image: xcode10.1
```

Travis support xcode version list:
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/objective-c/